# Sounds still playing in another frame

Tags: actionscript-3

Hey I am still getting some unwanted sound effects still playing in another frame, for example when I click my left mouse button which is also my jump button it will play the jump sound as well as playing the collect coins sound wierdly even though i remove each child from the stage when going to the game over screen.
Now im a bit unfamiliar with the sound channel so if its needed to be used please be kind and explain :)

In Frame 1:

```
var myMusic1:Sound = new Game_Over_Noise();
var myMusic2:Sound = new Jump_Noise();
var myMusic3:Sound = new Coin_Noise();
var myMusic4:Sound = new Power_Up_Noise();
var myMusic5:Sound = new Theme();
var channel:SoundChannel = myMusic5.play();
```

In Frame 8, Game Screen:

```
function doJump(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
if(!isJumping) //If the player is jumping.
{
jumpPower = 30; //Jump power is equal to 30.
isJumping = true; //isJumping variable is also equal to true.
 var channel:SoundChannel = myMusic2.play(); //Play sound effect.
}
}

function update(evt:Event):void
{
if(isJumping) //If the player is jumping.
{
MainChar.y -= jumpPower; //Subtract the value of jumpPower from the player's y co-ordinate.
jumpPower -= 2; //Decrease the value of jumppower by 2. 
}

if(MainChar.y + gravity < ground) //If the value of the player's Y co-ordinate and gravity is less than ground. 
MainChar.y += gravity; //Then add the value of gravity to the player's Y co-ordinates.
else //else
{
MainChar.y = ground; //The players Y co-ordinate is equal to ground.
isJumping = false; //Make isJumping equal to false.
}
}
```

in Frame 5, Game Over Screen:

```
SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

Now this stops the theme music and not the sound effects, now i actually dont mind the theme tune playing all the time but i would like ALL sound effects (game sounds) to only play in the game.

I know my coding isnt the best and efficient but its easily readible to me, I appreciate the help! :D

Comment: Does it fail to stop the sounds, or do the sounds continue to be triggered by keypresses? Looks to me like you need to remove your event listeners (they're active even when something is off-stage).

Comment: They continue to be triggered by key presses and collision, jumping using a mouseclick and the collision of the character with a collectable, somehow still colliding? Even though I remove all items off stage as soon as the game finishes, thanks alot for ur time :)

Comment: How would I go about removing the eventlistener?

Comment: I did  removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, doJump); when the collision takes place to end the game and it still does not work :(

Comment: In a similar way that you add them. Instead of `addEventListener()` use `removeEventListener()`.

Comment: Can you post the code that adds and removes the listeners?

Comment: Oh its working now, I LOVE you! I have 1 small other problem with calculating score? If you'd be so nice to help out :)

Comment: Awesome! Accept my answer and make a new question for the other problem and I'll see if I can help there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to remove your event listeners (they're active even when something is off-stage).